# Using object or collection as particle render not working

Tags: particles

Still pretty new to blender and i;m running in to a problem using particles.
I made a system which is basicly doing what i want it to. but when i try to change the actual particle from a standard 'halo' to a object or a collection, the particles disapear.
I've tried adjusting size and such but its not to small to see or anything. could use some help here.
[image]

Comment: What kind of object are you trying to use as your particles? Are you able to upload the .blend file for us to take a look at? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: First guess without more info is perhaps the origins for your particles are way off so they appear far away. Or they dont have an emissive material and are thus not visible. Are you adjusting the particles scale or the scale slide there?

Comment: It's emited from a geo nodes object with the modifier stack turned on, so it doesn't emit from 1 single point. The origin of my particles are centered and they have emissive materials. I've tried adjusting the size of the particles and the slider in the particle settings... The file is to big to upload on pasteall.org so here is a wetransfer link: https://we.tl/t-UR3EBPwJrd

Comment: It probably has something to do with the emitter being a geonodes object. because if i add a cube as a emiter and use the render - collection it just works. But ofcourse this is not what i want. so i need help here!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in your last Geometry node tree. You instanced geometry on points. The problem is that particles are emitted from mesh and instances are not mesh. So with that join geometry node, you incorporate 'Non-mesh' into the final objects mesh. So you just have to realize those instances to make them a part of the mesh and then it works.

edit: It's probably not a mesh issue. Rather maybe a bug where particles can't instance your objects because Geonodes is already instancing?
[image]

Comment: Mary me!!!
Thank you very much! Eventhough it doesn't make sense to me that it would show the 'halo' and hairs, but not as object or collection.

Comment: You're right it doesn't make sense. It's probably a bug.